# Crontab runs only a part of my script

Tags: python, linux, sh, cron

My script first executes two python scripts which write a temperature from a sensor to a file, which is then uploaded via ftp from within the .sh file.

For some reason the temperature only updates when I run the .sh file manually. When the crontab runs the script it does only upload the ftp, but it does not seem to run the python scripts, except for the the take_pic.py.

1. The crontab is executed from the root's crontab.
2. The python files are executable
3. The log files do not show anything
4. If I run the script manually everything works perfectly

**ftp.sh :**

```
echo "Run :$(date)" >> python_temp.log
python write_temp.py >> python_temp.log

python temp_to_file.py >> python_temp_to_file.log

#raspistill -o snapshot2.jpg -n -w 1280 -h 720

python takePic.py
sleep 3
HOST=XX                #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
USER=XX                #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
PASS=XX                #This is the password for the FTP user.
NOW=$(date +"%c")

#    echo beginne upload
    touch work
    ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
cd /bilder/
put snapshot2.jpg
rename snapshot2.jpg snapshot.jpg

put temp.js

bye
EOF
#    echo erfolgreicher upload
```

**temp_to_file.py**

```
import subprocess
import datetime
import sys

output = subprocess.check_output("temper-poll -q -c" , shell=True)
output = output.rstrip()

#write to file


fobj_out = open("temp.js","w")
fobj_out.write('document.write("' + output + '*C ");')
fobj_out.close()
```

**Crontab:**

```
*/5 * * * * /root/ftp.sh
```

Comment: Post also your crontab syntax. Have you gone through http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info ? there is good debugging info.

Comment: I think the problem is that subprocess_check_output is not working with crontab

Comment: You probably need to use full paths, as crontab does not know where it is running. Check the link I provided, there is good information.

Comment: Well the thing is, as I said the uploading is working like a charm every 5 min. So I dont think its the Crontab

Comment: If you want to solve the problem you may try to do some research. I indicated you some resources but you don't seem to have checked them. And if you think it is not a problem in the crontab, then just remove the crontab tag so we people with some knowledge on it won't be bothered.

Comment: Did you try any of the answers?

Comment: Yes My soution was to replace subprocess with another command

Comment: @fedorqui Also I checked your sources but there was no relevant info in them. Basically you could say crontab does not work with subprocess out of the box. You need to do the modifications named  by Timothy and Maya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly this problem occurs due to script file permission and ownership of script files. The same problem was faced by me. I found that my scrip owner was not a super user `e.g. root.`

So, you have to set the permission and ownership of your scrip as super user. Find below.

First of all edit your crontab as super user.

```
[abc@host] crontab -e
```

and save crontab `:wq!`

Now set permission for script

```
[abc@host] chmod +x script.sh
[abc@host] chown root:root script.sh
```

Now restart your crontab.

```
[abc@host] /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

Answer (score 1):

`>> If I run the script manually everything works perfectly`

You can include your .bash_profile in /root/ftp.sh before running any command.

`. /root/.bash_profile`

I have frequently faced issues like this with cron jobs.  You test them in shell when your profile is active, and when cron job runs, the environment (PATH and other things) is not available.

I looked at your two scripts, the first one uses only OS commands, but the second one calls temper-poll which may be not available to cron job.

Comment: The Solution is a combination of the two answers

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a shebang in your `ftp.sh` script, i.e. does it begin with a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` line that you did not show here?

If it does not, you either need to add it, or in your crontab you must run `bash /root/ftp.sh`. Otherwise your script won't execute correctly.

Comment: did not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that that the python interpreter can'f find you takePic.py script.

Because a cronjob is executed in the users home directory (e.g.: /home/myuser/). So use the full path of your script:

```
python /some/path/takePic.py >> /some/path/python_temp.log
```